# When using Node's fs.readFile(), should I prepend the path with __dirname?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, path

Example:

```
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/file'), callback);
```

versus

```
fs.readFile('path/to/file', callback);
```

Both seem to work, so I'm wondering if I can just skip the `__dirname` prefix, i.e. if there is any reason to prepend it.

Answer (score 2):

From the [node docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname),

```
__dirname
```

is the name of the directory that the currently executing script resides in.

This will allow for flexibility across multiple deployments (eg: development / production).

If you are not deploying to any remote servers, you probably don't need the __dirname tag.

Answer (score 2):

It is often better to use __dirname because it won't care where node is running from (i.e. the cwd).

Try running your application from a different directory - the `__dirname` variant will still succeed while the other will not.  I.e. instead of `node app.js` run `node foo/app.js` assuming `app.js` lives in a directory named `foo`.