# Node filesystem path is pointing to wrong spot

Tags: javascript, node.js, atom-editor

I'm currently writing a plugin for atom, my issue is that i'm trying to look through files local to my project, but the wrong path is always grabbed by node.

E.g if I call this `"atom.project.getPaths()"` i'm returned the exact path to my project which i'd expect node to use.

```
C:\Users\TomYeoman\github\package-name
```

However when i'm trying to iterate through the files in this project, using nodes build in "fs" command in the same file

```
fs.readFile('js_uncompiled/approval_functions.js')
```

I end up with the error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\TomYeoman\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.15.0\js_uncompiled\approval_functions.js'
```

Has anyone faced this before, should I override the default FS behaviour or is there something obvious i'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: can you use `path.join` function along with `__dirname` ??  fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/file'), callback);

Comment: you may find some reference on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175779/when-using-nodes-fs-readfile-should-i-prepend-the-path-with-dirname

Comment: @RJ- Perfect it's now recognizing my package path when I run it, it's a bit of a pain in the ass that packages such as this https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-in-files do not work for me though as they return a broken path mentioned in the original post. Do you think this is intended or worth a PR? I thought atom was meant to play nicely with all packages out the box. (Sorry this might be past your knowledge here, guess i'll just have to recreate the functionality which already exists in these node packages if not)

Comment: Well, I'm very new to Atom, so no idea about external packages. I did not understood what you meant by PR either..

Comment: Ok fair enough, PR is a "pull request" on the "https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-in-files" repository, So you push code to the repo and ask for it to updated with a path resolve that works nicely with all platforms :).

Comment: Thanks @does_not_compute

Comment: You do need to use `path` with the Atom API for this. It works as expected.